# How can I display an image over a video player in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, vlc, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-layout

I made a video player using tkinter. I'm using the vlc media player to play the video. Now I want to have an image display on top of the video as the video plays, its a pointer of some sort and needs to move around on the video based on the x and y coordinates in a list. I can't seem to have the image show on top of the video as the video plays. Is there any way to do this?

I tried making it a label setting the image as label.image. That worked but the image always had a white background around it (the image is a circle). Is there a way to make the label transparent so that the video player is shown instead of the white background? I also tried using video_canvas.create_image() but the image would disappear as soon as I would open the video.
I have a video_canvas that then opens the vlc media player. I also tried using video_canvas.lift ad video_canvas.tag_raise() but that didn't work either.

Comment: https://www.codespeedy.com/video-streaming-in-tkinter-with-python/ and https://github.com/orenber/videoPlayer/blob/master/GUI/VideoPlayer.py and https://webninjadeveloper.com/python/python-3-tkinter-project-to-play-mp4-video-files-with-advanced-controls-using-tkvideoplayer-library-gui-desktop-app/

Comment: Post a [mre]. Anyway, you can't do that with Python-vlc, because Tcl/Tk doesn't support a widget with a transparent background.